# String Matching and finding 1 of similar values

Tags: powershell

using a program called GAM I run a command like this.

```
$sharedID = (& gam user $EMAIL show teamdrives matchname $SharedName | Where-Object {$_ -match "Shared Drive ID: " })
```

The problem is that I have a few Shared Drives with similar names. I am getting a return of two values that are large strings with lots of information.

Example Names. I would only need house.

```
House
HouseFire
House Boat
```

I need the shared drive ID that equals the name. Instead I am getting

```
Shared Drive X, ID y
Shared Drive A, ID F
```

I can't modify the GAM command so whatever the answer is. The answer needs to happen in the pipeline or after it on new line(s) of code.

I tried

```
Where-Object {$_ -match $SName -and $_ -match "Shared Drive ID: " }
```

This one above gave me nothing. I get that.

and

```
Where-Object {$_ -match $SName }
```

the above is still giving me 2 answers.

I know how to get the ID out of the string if I get down to 1 string.

Comment: You really want the match to be the last word on the line.  Match is using Regex and the dollar sign indicates end of line.  So you want a space followed by the string and the dollar sign : matchname (' ' + $SharedName + '$')

Comment: `Where-Object {$_ -match (' ' + "$SName" + '$')}` This gets me to one string answer but I am losing the other information. @jdweng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following Regex :

```
$drives = @("Shared Drive X, ID y","Shared Drive A, ID F")
$pattern = "^Shared Drive\s(?<drive>[^,]+), ID (?<id>.*)"
foreach($drive in $drives)
{
   $drive -match $pattern | Out-Null
   Write-Host "drive = "$Matches.drive "id = " $Matches.id
}
```